# How to keep objects one-to-many RestKit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have be confused with mapping relationship one-to-many in RestKit. My json looks like this

```
object: {
    sub_objects: [{sub_object}]
}
```

I need to autocomplete items for relationship `array` in core-data. array may be empty but objects must be leave.

Here are my object mapping

```
[objMapping mapKeyPath:@"sub_objects" toRelationship:@"subObjects"  withMapping:subObjMapping];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the second string should be `@"subObject"` without the final "s"?